# Rolling Listener and Midnight filename not correct

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I am using RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData with Enterprise 5  and set the rollingInterval to Midnight.

The current log file is:
myapplication.log

The log file rotates every midnight (local server time), say the clock reaches March 8, 2013 12:00:00 AM, it renames the current log file to myapplication.2013-03-08.log.

myapplication.2013-03-08.log
myapplication.log

Indeed the actual content of myapplication.2013-03-08.log is for previous day from March 7, 2013  12:00:00 AM to March 7, 2013 23:59:59 PM.

Is there any settings that I can specific the log file name so that it does "date-1" at Midnight?  I want the filename to be myapplication.2013-03-07.log instead. Any idea how to do this?

Here is the config:

```
<listeners>
<add name="Flat File Trace Listener"     
   type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.
  TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, 
  Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"                    
  listenerDataType=
  "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.
  Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData,
 Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0,     Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"                 
 fileName="C:\myapplication.log"  rollInterval="Midnight"              
 header="" footer="" formatter="Text Formatter"/>
 </listeners>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to change the out of the box behavior.  You would have to implement a custom trace listener with the desired behavior or modify the RollingFlatFileTraceListener source code.